# HTML List classes

Tags: html, css

So for my Tafe work, one requirment is to have an unordered list.
I have a menu, but it clashes with the list I'm attempting to make.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tHLY7/1/

If you remove:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

It shows the list how I want but ruins my menu.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the display:inline to be on the nav only.

```
#Menubar ul li { display: inline; }
```

Comment: That was fast, too the point and worked perfectly.
You're a life saver!

Comment: Any time. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

your styling `li { display: inline }` will apply to ALL `<li>` on the page, no matter where they are. I would suggest targeting *only* the `<li>` that are part of your menu. In your case,

`#menu li { display: inline; }`.

Or maybe,

`#Menubar li { display: inline }`.

(one word of note though, ID's and classes in HTML are by convention, all lowercase, so you should change `<div id="Menubar">` to `<div id="menubar">`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some improvement overall: http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/tHLY7/4/

**Here are a few tips**

1.) You should never use "#ID" for styling purposes, just use #ID for javascript hooks, always use ".class" for styling and like someone else said, keep it lowercase.

2.) Always use a "reset.css" file. I've attached the best reset file I know that exists from HTML5 boilerplates website. You can take care of a lot of  your "base" styles in that file. Use a stylesheet.css file after your reset.css file

3.) Like someone else said, if you have multiple elements on a page (in this case, ul's) then you must target that specific ul through a class name and tell it specifically what you want it to do.. otherwise it will take the style from the reset.css file.

4.) 2 very important styles have been added!

- Clear Fix (I'm calling this ".row", This is the best way to make things drop to the next line (like hitting the "return" key in microsoft word)
- Box sizing is you're best friend! It makes "padding" act correctly and doesn't add space to your elements that have it. I gave it the "*" to apply on everything.

  ```
          /* Box sizing is you're best friend! It makes "padding" act correctly and doesn't add space to your elements that have it. */
          *, *:after, *:before { margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  }

          /* Clear Fix - This is the best way to make things drop to the next line (like hitting the "return" key in microsoft word ) */
          .row:before, .row:after { content: " "; display: table; }
          .row:after { clear: both; }
          .row { *zoom: 1; clear: both;  }

          /* This "wrapper" goes around everything and makes your content stay in the middle of the page */
          .wrapper { width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; } 

          /* Navigation */
          .menu { background: #000; width: 100%; float: left; display: block; }
          .menu ul { color: #fff; float: right; }
          .menu ul li { float: left; display: block; }
          .menu ul li a { display: block; color: #fff; padding: .25em 1em; border-left: 1px solid #fff; }
          .menu ul li a.active { background: #333333; display: block; color: #fff; padding: .25em 1em; border-left: 1px solid #fff; }
          .menu ul li a:hover { background: #333333; color: #fff; }

          /* Main Content */
          .main { padding: .5em 0; }
          .main h1 { margin: .5em 0; }
          .main ul {  }
          .main ul li { list-style: inside; }
  ```

I hope this helps!